# jade loop not able to access variable in node.js file

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I've been searching for the solution to this for days and would love any solutions or recommendations.

I am building a very simple blog with node.js, express, and mongo db according to [this how to node tutorial](http://howtonode.org/express-mongodb). I am doing this as practice in order to understand node better, as I'm not very well-versed yet.

I followed all instructions, taking into account differences in versions, and everything runs fine until I get to the heading in the tutorial, "A View to Kill", where I send some dummy data to a jade file to be rendered.

If I leave the code in my app.js file as this with no jade file being passed into it:

```
var articleProvider= new ArticleProvider();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  articleProvider.findAll(function(error, docs){
      res.send(docs);
  });
})

app.listen(3000);
```

I get a render of the data object.

But when I pass in the jade file to be rendered, I get the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

...which refers to the each loop in my jade file (line 3), which is here:

```
h1= title
#articles
    - each article in articles
      div.article
        div.created_at= article.created_at
        div.title 
            a(href="/blog/"+article._id)!= article.title
        div.body= article.body
```

[Here is the link](https://github.com/araeb/blog-question) to the git of the whole damn thing. ANY help at all is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `articles` reference is undefined. Try changing your render code to the following:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    articleProvider.findAll(function(error, docs){
        res.render('index.jade', {
            articles: docs
        });
    });
});
```